# Reflexive and relation

Tags: soft-question

Please give me feedback on my answer to this question.
Question:
 For all $x,y\in R$ define that $x\equiv y$ if $x^{2}=y^{2}$. Then $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation on $R$, there are infinitely many equivalence classes, one of them consists of one element and the rest consist of two elements.
Answer:
False, since;

$x\equiv y$
  if $x^{2}=y^{2}$
 on $R$

To show $\equiv$
  is reflexive, we need to show that ,

$\forall x\in R:X\equiv x.$

Let $x\in R$,
  $X\equiv x$
  if $X^{2}=x^{2}$
 , which is obvious.

$[x]\triangleq:\{y\in R/x\equiv y\}$

$[0]=[y\in R/0\equiv y\},$
 when $y=0$,

Then $y^{2}=0^{2}=0$

Thus; there are not many infinity many equivalence classes.

Comment: Hint: $(-1)^2=(1)^2 \implies -1\equiv 1$

Comment: What did you try? What is the doubt?

Comment: i don't know how to do this question

Comment: Do you know the definition of an equivalence relation?

Comment: Why do you use both $X$ and $x$? They're supposed to mean the same number, right? Font/case usually means that this is not the case. Also, the last line is confused. You found a single equivalence containing one number. Why would that say anything about the number of equivalance classes? Actually you cannot even begin to talk about equivalence classes before you have shown that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same
as an earlier problem 
I answered that
I can't find.

The "trick" is that
$x^2 = y^2$
has two $y$'s for any $x$
(except for $x=0$):
$y = x$ and $y = -x$.

Comment: Is this answer correct.True. To show that \equiv
 is reflexive we need to show that \forall x\in\mathbb{R}
 :x=x.
 Let x\in\mathbb{R}
 , x\equiv\mbox{\ensuremath{x}}
 if x^{2}=x^{2},
  which is obvious.

[x]
 =\{y\in\mathbb{R}
 |x\equiv y\}
 =[0]=\{y\in\mathbb{R}|0\equiv y\}=\{0\}
 . Hence y^{2}
 =0^{2}
  =0
  which implies that y=0
 .

Comment: @user153017 Tip: You need to place \$ symbols before and after MathJax text for it to display in human readable form.  Also, yes, marty cohen's answer is correct. $\{0\}$ is the only equivalence class with a single member; the rest of the uncountably many equivalence classes each contain two members: a positive real and the corresponding negative real.

Answer (score 1):

**General** (to remember)

Whenever $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function the relation on $X$ defined by: $a\equiv b$ if $f(a)=f(b)$ is an equivalence relation. This is not difficult to check:

$f(a)=f(a)$ (reflexivity)

$f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow f(b)=f(a)$ (symmetry)

$f(a)=f(b)\wedge f(b)=f(c)\Rightarrow f(a)=f(c)$ (transitivity)

The equivalence classes are exactly the fibers of $f$, i.e. the sets: $$[a]=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=f(a)\}$$

---

**Application**

You are dealing with $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x^2$ and can apply this right away.

For every $a\in\mathbb R$ we find equivalenceclass: $[a]=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x^2=a^2\}=\{a,-a\}$

Evidently $[0]=\{0\}$ so has exactly one element. This in contrast with the other classes that all contain exactly two elements.

On base of $0\le a<b\Rightarrow[a]\ne[b]$ we conclude that there are infinitely many classes.