# Show that R is an equivalence relation on X for x, y in X iff f(x) = f(y)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

$f:X→Y$

$x,y ∈ X,xRy$ iff $f(x) = f(y)$

Show that R is an equivalence relation on X.

Also when $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ with $x \mapsto x^2$ for all $x∈R$ find the equivalence classes of R relative to this situation.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen i wrote f(x) = f(y) implies that f(x)Rf(y) which implies xRy. i know this is wrong:p

Comment: The statement '$R$ is reflexive' can be restated as '$f(x)=f(x)$ for each $x$'. This is evidently true. Likewise you can do with symmetry and transitivity. Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/807557/75923)

Comment: This is every equivalence relation.

Comment: See also: [Prove that the relation on $X$ given by $x\sim y$ if $f(x)=f(y)$ is an equivalence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236777)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start by the easiest condition - reflexivity. Is $xRx$? The answer is yes because clearly $f(x)=f(x)$.

Transitivity: if $xRy$ and $yRz$ then $f(x)=f(y)$ and $f(y)=f(z)$, but clearly $f(x)=f(y)=f(z)$ and thus $f(x)=f(z)$ which implies $xRz$.

Symmetry is easy, I leave this as an exercise.

Now for $x \mapsto x^2$. We denote $x \sim y \iff x^2 = y^2$. Solving this equation yields $x = \pm y$. Thus $x \sim y \iff x = \pm y$. There are only two such $x$'s and they are $y$ and $-y$ so each class is $[y] = \{ y , - y \}$ and $[0]=\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: many thanks, but just why is 0 in this equivalence class?

Comment: $0$ is its own equivalence class, since it is the unique solution of $x^2=0$.